# Update one mysql table from another where third table matches old id to new id

Tags: mysql

I need to copy data from an old table into a new table, but the ids are different between the tables. A third table exists that matches the old id to the new id.

What query would I use to take the new id and use it to get the old id from the matching table, then use the old id to get the data from the old table and write it to the new table?

```
New table:

id | value
------------
1  | this
2  | content
3  | will
4  | be
5  | overwritten

Old table:

id | value
------------
6  | where
7  | when
8  | who
9  | how
10 | why

ID Matching table:

newid | oldid
------------
1     | 6
2     | 7
3     | 8
4     | 9
5     | 10

New table after update:

id | value
------------
1  | where
2  | when
3  | who
4  | how
5  | why
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UPDATE with JOIN:

```
UPDATE `new` n
INNER JOIN `bind` b ON
    b.newid = n.id
INNER JOIN `old` o ON
    b.oldid = o.id
SET n.value = o.value;
```